# AWS Cognito PreTokenGeneration handler lambda function - what are the typescript types for (event, context, callback)

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

The [documentation for the AWS Cognito Pre Token Generation function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) has node example code, but no typescript example code.

Are there typescript types I can import to strongly type the three parameters passed to the handler function?

```js
import { TypeA, TypeB, TypeC } from '???'; // Are these defined by AWS somewhere?
exports.handler = (event: TypeA, context: TypeB, callback: TypeC) => {
  event.response = {
    // the good stuff goes here
  }
  callback(null, event)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { Callback, Context, PreTokenGenerationTriggerEvent } from "aws-lambda";

exports.handler = (event: PreTokenGenerationTriggerEvent, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
  event.response = {
    // the good stuff goes here
  }
  callback(null, event)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[@types/aws-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/aws-lambda) contains type definitions for AWS Lambda. Specifically, events of type `PreTokenGenerationTriggerEvent` from [`pre-token-generation.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/trigger/cognito-user-pool-trigger/pre-token-generation.d.ts)

Also, you can use an `async` function instead of a callback.

```
import { Context, PreTokenGenerationTriggerEvent } from "aws-lambda";

export const handler = async (
  event: PreTokenGenerationTriggerEvent,
  context: Context
): Promise<PreTokenGenerationTriggerEvent> => {
  console.log(`Event: ${JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)}`);

  // good stuff goes here, like
  event.response.claimsOverrideDetails = {
    claimsToAddOrOverride: {
      'custom:claim': 'custom value'
    }
  };
  return event;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the simplest solution is using the universal type `Handler` from `aws-lambda`.

```
import { Handler } from 'aws-lambda';

export const preSignUp: Handler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log(event.request.userAttributes);
    return event;
};
```

It's good for cases when you just want compilable TS code and don't want to load additional types. If you want a detailed event type - use Kevin's answer